# Static class updates are not visible from another file

Tags: php, caching, static

I am trying to use a static class as cache.
The aim is to write to the static class from different files and finally be able to see the changes from a check file.

**The problem:**

The value of [token_1] is being updated by the first file,
but the last view-file shows the value "placeholder" instead of value "12".

**Observations:**

I suspect the lack of seen updated data, might be the fact several files runs an include, making each include to load the default of the data file.

---

**File: ConfigurationData.class.php**

```
<?php

class ConfigurationData
{
      public static $tokens = [
        "token_1" => "placeholder"
      ];
}
```

**File: 1_inject_data.php**

```
<?php

include 'ConfigurationData.class.php';

ConfigurationData::$tokens["token_1"] = 12;

echo "token_1 has been updated to value " .
  "[" . ConfigurationData::$tokens["token_1"] . "]";
echo " in class [ConfigurationData]" . "." . "\n\n";
```

**File: 2_check_configuration_data.php**

```
<?php
include 'ConfigurationData.class.php';
echo ConfigurationData::$tokens["token_1"];
```

---

**Results:**

[1_inject_data.php]:

```
token_1 has been updated to value [12] in class [ConfigurationData].
```

[2_check_configuration_data.php]

```
placeholder
```

**Expected results:**
[2_check_configuration_data.php]

```
12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php does not have persistent state across calls. when you call your different scripts, each starts with a clear memory. if you need caching across multiple calls, there are many ready-to-use solutions out there, my personal favourite is using REDIS for caching as it interoperates well with other stacks or instances.